# yii- help using many-many relationship

Tags: frameworks, yii, many-to-many, table-relationships

All, I need to get a table value based on the primary key from it table then I used that on the other table. I can ilustrate my question like this:

**table a**

- id_a
- att_a1
- att_a2
- att_a3
- att_a4
- att_a5

**table b** (dummy table)

- id_a
- id_c
- percentage_a1
- percentage_a2

**table c** (here i need to calculate my result)

- id_c
- att_c1 `= att_a1*percentage_a1`
- att_c2 `= att_a2*percentage_a2`
- att_c3 `= att_c2+att_a4`

How could I do that in Yii?

Any response pls
Thx, my regards

Comment: where will the table's information be get from table c ?

Comment: – Bàn Chân Trần - the table c attributes : att_c1 was the result of table a's attribute multiplying with the table b's attribute = att_a1 * percentage_a1, so that the table c would get the value by getting the information from table a and b.

Comment: -stu - i've trying to generate the model, controller for each table and crud generator just for the table a and c because the table b had composite pk which means i can't use gii to generate my crud. i modified my table c model relation with this : public function relations()
 {
  return array(
   //'kelayakan' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'KelayakanUsaha', 'kelayakan_id'),
   'tabelBs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'tabelB', 'id_b'),
   'tabelA'      => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'tabelA', array('id_a'=>'id'),'through'=>'tabel_b'),
  );
 }

Comment: what i wanna do and confused is how can i calculate the table c using the data from table a and multiply with table b (percentage) and save the result in table c. the percentage_a1 and percentage_a2 attributes from table b was depend on the data from table a and will be save in table c. i really don't know how to doing this using yii framework. thanks

Comment: sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that you need to do.  You need to establish a many to many relationship between the two tables inside the class of the middle table.  You need to set has settings for each of the outer tables.

Follow these instructions:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr